# Bluetooth Headphones mic doesnt work even with (HSP/HFP)

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

my Bluetooth Headphones (literally any pair of them) work with both HSP/HFP and A2DP Sink but the mic is not working on either of both profiles. I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a 64-bit Laptop.

Comment: What have you tried to know they do not work? The mic should not work on the A2DP profile.

Comment: I have used an online voice recorder and also opened the settings and then sound and watched the bar that is there for the mic to see how much noise is getting in. I know that the mic should not work on the A2DP Profile. But it doesn't work on the other Profile aswell which bothers me.